# Have a key value pair as logstash output, by only using grok filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elk

I am working on a spring boot project and using ELK stack for logging and auditing. I need a logstash.conf file which will process logs and the output can have dynamic key-value pairs. This output data will be used for auditing.

*Adding an example for better clarity*

**Example:**

Sample log:

```
[INFO] [3b1d04f219fc43d18ccb6cb22db6cff4] 2021-10-13_13:43:09.074 Audit_ key1:value1| key2:value2| key3:value3| keyN:valueN
```

Required logstash output:

```
{
  "logLevel": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "threadId": [
    [
      "3b1d04f219fc43d18ccb6cb22db6cff4"
    ]
  ],
  "timeStamp": [
    [
      "2021-10-13_13:43:09.074"
    ]
  ],
  "class": [
    [
      "Audit_"
    ]
  ],
  "key1": [
    [
      "value1"
    ]
  ],
  "key2": [
    [
      "value2"
    ]
  ],
  "key3": [
    [
      "value3"
    ]
  ],
  "keyN": [
    [
      "valueN"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Note:

- "key" will always be a word or string value
- "value" can be word, numeric or sentence(string with spaces)
- ":" is the separator between key and value
- "|" is the separator between key-value pairs
- The number of key-value pairs can vary.

Can someone suggest/help me with the match pattern to be used here? I am only allowed to use grok filter.

Comment: Any reason to only use grok? This is easily done using grok and the kv filter, but I do not know if it is possible with just grok as the number of fields and the values of those fields can vary and some of them can break your grok pattern.

Comment: A logstash.conf file is already running, and I want to use the same conf file. The current conf file only has grok filter. If I am adding a kv filter in the existing logstash.conf file have an impact on the existing flow?

Comment: Well you can always use logstash conditionals and check which data flow the event belongs to. I can't tell you how exactly because you never mentioned the other flow or other logstash configuration in question. But I don't see a reason why you wouldn't use `kv` filter, I'm pretty sure you can't do it with only `grok`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for guidance Filip and leandrojmp!

Just using a grok filter for this, would make it very complex and also it wont support dynamic key-value pairs.

So I went with a combination of grok followed by kv filter. And this approach worked for me.

Sample Log:

```
[INFO] [3b1d04f219fc43d18ccb6cb22db6cff4] 2021-10-13_13:43:09.074 _Audit_ key1:value1| key2:value2| key3:value3| keyN:valueN
```

**logstash.conf file:**

```
input {
  beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
filter {
  grok {
  match => {"message" => "\[%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}\]\ \[%{WORD:traceId}\]\ (?<timestamp>[0-9\-_:\.]*)\ %{WORD:class}\ %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]}
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }
    if [class] == "_Audit_" {
      kv {
        source => "message"
        field_split => "&"
        value_split => "="
        remove_field => ["message"]
      }
    }
}
output {
  if [class] == "_Audit_" {
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "audit-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
  }
  else {
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "normal-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
  }
}
```